# All possible combinations of two lists

Tags: combinatorics

I have two lists: First list are appointment ids: (50,51,52) Second list are warehouses (2, 3, 4, 5)

I'm trying determine correct number of possibilities of appointments and which warehouses they can ship out of.

For this example, would it be correct to say it is 4*4*4*4 = 256 ?

Edit: up to two appointments can happen in a given warehouse

Comment: Some clarifications please - can more than $1$ appointment happen in $1$ warehouse?

Comment: Ishan, yes more than 1 appointment can happen. for this example, we could say that up to 2 appointments can happen at in any given warehouse

Comment: So, is the problem now in how many ways you can distribute those (in your example: three) appointments among those (in your example: four) warehouses so that there aren't more than two appointments in a single warehouse? For example (again, in your example): warehouse $2$ has appointments $50$ and $52$, warehouse $4$ has appointment $51$, and warehouses $3$ and $5$ have no appointments? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Biship, yes that is correct. FYI in reality there are up to eighteen(18) appointments and only four (4) warehouses. I was just trying to keep the numbers low.

Comment: 18+24=42 actually.

Comment: Roddy, how are you coming up with that # ? :)